# Why is querying posts messing up my pages?

Tags: posts, query-posts, get-posts

I am working on a theme at the moment and I have set up a post template.

This post template is linked to some custom post types.

When I query_posts for my post type on the actual post template itself it makes the content disappear for some reason? Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks,
Mark

My loop is as follows:

```
<?php
    $query = 'posts_per_page=10&post_type=articles';
    $queryObject = new WP_Query($query);

    // The Loop...
    if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
        while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
            $queryObject->the_post(); the_title(); the_content();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes, you missed publishing the relevant code here :)

Comment: <?php
$query = 'posts_per_page=10&post_type=articles';
$queryObject = new WP_Query($query);
// The Loop...
if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
 while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
  $queryObject->the_post();
  the_title();
  the_content();
 }
}
?>

Comment: Mark, sorry... first welcome to WPSE. After posting a question, you can edit it, adding new info to interact with some answer or comment. Your code belongs to the question, where it can be formatted for better visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`wp_reset_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) after your loop to restore the global post data for the main loop.

Comment: I had an idea that it would be a reset but I thought it was reset_query forgot about the wp in front as this has to find it in the db right?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, while using [`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) isn't necessarily wrong, it is an unnecesary extra operation, if run after a secondary query with a new instance of the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class. The `$wp_query` object isn't altered, so it needs not be reset. Only the `$post` global requires a reset. Hence, [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) would be sufficient in this case.

See [/wp-includes/query.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4/wp-includes/query.php#L95) for reference:

```
/**
* Destroy the previous query and set up a new query.
*
* This should be used after {@link query_posts()} and before another {@link
* query_posts()}. This will remove obscure bugs that occur when the previous
* wp_query object is not destroyed properly before another is set up.
*
* @since 2.3.0
* @uses $wp_query
*/
function wp_reset_query() {
    unset($GLOBALS['wp_query']);
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

/**
* After looping through a separate query, this function restores
* the $post global to the current post in the main query
*
* @since 3.0.0
* @uses $wp_query
*/
function wp_reset_postdata() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( !empty($wp_query->post) ) {
        $GLOBALS['post'] = $wp_query->post;
        setup_postdata($wp_query->post);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah right. Cheers Johannes. That is extremely useful information on the side of looking at wp_queries. Starting to get my head around it now.

Comment: @user1341368 If you're in the process of wrapping your head around queries in general, you should read this [extremely informative answer by Rarst](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)